# Android url download calculate progress?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have made a download method that works fine. It takes a **`String url`** and returns the downloaded **`InputStream`** which gets processed by **`XMLPullParser`**. Now I want to add a progressbar to the download. I have figured out that I can somehow use **`getContentLength()`** on **`HttpURLConnection`** but I do not know how to calculate the progressbar after that.

This is my code:

```
public static InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(25000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
    conn.connect();
    int size = conn.getContentLength();
    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

            //calculate the progress

    return stream;      
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please use the search before posting questions that have already been answered. [Here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

Comment: I have seen those but non of them actually returns an `InputStream` after the download which my parser needs. Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to parse the content afterwards, you have (at least) two options:

- Keep track of current position in the stream, as suggested in [that Google groups answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/vu22daRhVPw/uRXroXI24Y4J). You have then an accurate progress as it represents both parsing and downloading progress.
- Download the stream to a temp file (and show progress for that) and then you pass a FileInputStream to your parser (and show some more progress if required, but that should be fast compared to the download, you could consider downloading as 90% of the progress and parsing as the remaining 10% for instance).